# why ongenerate route calling my dashboard screen's init method?.....even though i'm still on login or signup screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i'm using **flutter_bloc** as a state management and the problem lies within this route file, it's calling dashboard's init method as soon as app starts, which i don't want.

(this is routing)

```
class AppRouter {
  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case SplashScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SplashScreen());

      case IntroScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => IntroScreen());

      case LoginScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen());

      case SignUpScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpScreen());

      case DashboardScreen.routeName:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DashboardScreen());

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No route defined for ${routeSettings.name}'),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

(this is startup logic)

```
class Init {
  Future<String> initialize() async {
    await _registerServices();
    await _loadSettings();
    return await _loadInitialRoute();
  }

  late final SharedPreferences _prefs;
  late final SessionManager _sessionManager;
  late final AuthRepositoryImpl _authRepository;
  late final bool _userSeenIntro;
  late final String? _presistentSession;

  Future<void> _registerServices() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _sessionManager = SessionManager();
    _authRepository = AuthRepositoryImpl.instance;
  }

  Future<void> _loadSettings() async {
    _userSeenIntro = _prefs.getBool(AppConstants.IS_USER_SEEN_INTRO) ?? false;
    _presistentSession = await _sessionManager.getSessionToken();
    await _authRepository.recoverSession(_presistentSession);
  }

  Future<String> _loadInitialRoute() async {
    if (_userSeenIntro && _presistentSession != null) {
      print('inside dashboardscreen.routename');
      return DashboardScreen.routeName;
    } else if (_userSeenIntro && _presistentSession == null) {
      return LoginScreen.routeName;
    } else {
      _prefs.setBool(AppConstants.IS_USER_SEEN_INTRO, true);
      return IntroScreen.routeName;
    }
  }
}
```

[this is my onGenerate routes and i don't know why flutter calling my dashboard's init method and even build method too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elOYZ.png)

[this is my startup logic I'm setting initial route in material app on the basis of sharedPrefernces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/camQ7.png)

Comment: Edit and add code content to check.

Comment: hy! sorry for that, added!

Comment: your variable `_userSeenIntro` is stored in sharedPrefs so it would be true as you are making it in initialRoute and you are not making it false. and for second variable `_presistentSession` you are using `await` for it so it will get the token so it won't be also `null` so condition becomes true that why it is calling dashboard's `initstate`